# Postgres generated columns returning 0 for each record

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a generated column in postgre but it's not generating right. I currently have a column for each state's number of electors and cost (for an election game)
and I want to create a column that generates that state's value which divides the two then multiplies it by 1000. Here is my table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.states (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar NOT NULL,
    "cost" int8 NULL,
    electors int2 NULL
);
```

Here is the query that I made to insert the generated column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.states
ADD value float(8) generated always as (electors * 1000 / cost) STORED;
```

This is my result. Every column is 0 but I should be getting float values that are less than 1 and greater than 0:

[image: Query result]

Comment: It looks like the math is being done on ints, so 0.3 = 0 and then the result is being stored as a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer division:

```
select (3 *1000)/10000; 
0
```

Do something like:

```
select round((3 * 1000)/10000::numeric, 2);  
0.30
```

Or translated:

**UPDATE**

```
(round((electors * 1000) / cost::numeric, 2))
```

Comment: (round(electors * 1000 / cost::numeric, 2)) works, but some values don't get rounded and I'll get something like 0.30000001.

Comment: See **UPDATE**. Try `select round((electors * 1000) / cost::numeric, 2) from public.states` to see what is returned?

Comment: I don't see a difference @Adrian Klaver

Comment: In your question provide example of what works and what does not.